# How to access a FDF through a java HTTP request

Tags: java, http, fdf

I have a PDF form with a submit button. The submit button action is set up to send the FDF with the content fields to a URL. A java class is run when this URL is accessed. There is a field in the PDF called FName.  When I use the Http Request object to get the field FName null is returned.  How can I access the FDF data in my java class.  I have included the JFDFTK.jar file in my class path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're testing on Windows, try something like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to trace the HTTP traffic between your PDF and the server side code. You should then be able to see if the value is actually sent from the PDF as you expect.

If you see the field being sent, then maybe post your Java code so we can see how you're handling the HTTP request.